# angular2 bind events to observable object

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am try to bind key up event and observable object, each time press a key in textbox field, I want to log "you have pressed:"+key string in console, there isnt any error shown but also nothing occurs when pressing keys..

```
 /// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'search-samp',
    template: '<input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">'
})
export class SearchComponent {
    constructor(){
         var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup").map(e=> {e.target.value});
         keyups.subscribe(data => { 
             debugger
             console.log("you have pressed:"+data)});
    }
 }
```

Why its not working ?

EDITED:

```
 var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup").map(function(e){debugger});
```

cant reach debugger point inside map function..it looks event never binded properly.. but why ?

Comment: To log keyup you can use `<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You should wait until `ngAfterViewInit` is called (there are no template's elements in DOM yet)

2) You have to change the code of the `map` function either

```
.map(e => { return e.target.value; })
```

or

```
.map(e => e.target.value)
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ps3l0AV7YvHfeh5x1h8?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for answer but map fuction is same already in original.. just look the code piece I share before edit.. I just changed it to explain map function never trigged..

Comment: yes I did it with you way and it works fine but whatif I want to run it inside a constructor I saw it in tutorial its possible but if I copy this code inside it  Cannot find name 'ngAfterViewInit'" error occurs.. ?

Comment: I also understood now my component constructor function never called so observable never created :)) thank you..